# Can I get the user wall status in facebook using as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I get the user wall status in Facebook using as3?
Using me/feed/...something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Checkout the AS3/Facebook SDK [here](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/) its pretty well maintained and will do exactly what you are asking.